# how to setup error prone with gradle (getting various errors)

Tags: java, gradle, errorprone

I am trying to setup error prone using gradle, however everything ive tried gives me some kind of error:

To test I have setup a simple hello world java program using gradle, which without error prone compiles fine.
Then I read: https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-errorprone-plugin
found from the install guide and tried this in the build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id("net.ltgt.errorprone") version "2.3.3"
}

group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    errorprone("com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core:2.3.3")

}
```

This gave me this error:

```
Plugin [id: 'net.ltgt.errorprone', version: '2.3.3'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'net.ltgt.errorprone:net.ltgt.errorprone.gradle.plugin:2.3.3')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

I changed `2.3.3` to `latest.version` and got the same error

Then I found this https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/net.ltgt.errorprone and tried version number 0.8.1.
I need to be able to use java11 so can't use gradle 4.x as far as I understand.

Also if anybody knows of an actual repository that has used error prone with gradle that I could look at I would be very grateful :)

My gradle wrapper properties is set to use gradle version 5.4.1

Comment: The gradle build file you posted has no sign of anything related to errorprone.

Comment: But given that the latest version of the plugin is 0.8.1, I'm not surprised it can't find the version 2.3.3.

Comment: OK, so you're using version 2.3.3 of the plugin, but the latest version is 0.8.1. And you have a missing double quote at the beginning of the version, making the build file incorrect.

Comment: ah sorry, added now, I tried 0.8.1 and got
 ```Could not find com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core:0.8.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_core/0.8.1/error_prone_core-0.8.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_core/0.8.1/error_prone_core-0.8.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :```

Also tried latest.release for the version  number and got the original error (except the 2.3.3 was swapped for latest.release in the error message)

Comment: You need to realize that there are two different versions involved here: the version of com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core (2.3.3), and the version of the errorprone gradle plugin (net.ltgt.errorprone): 0.8.1. Don't use the same version for both, since those are different things.

Comment: Ah thankyou, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Solved as below

1. Add Gradle plugin to build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id("net.ltgt.errorprone") version "1.1.0"
}
```

[Release versions](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-errorprone-plugin/releases)

2. Add dependency to `error_prone_core` in build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    errorprone("com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core:2.3.3")
}
```

[Releases](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.errorprone/error_prone_core)
3. Build project, this will add `errorprone` configuration namespace
4. If you are using java-8, need to add additional dependency too.

```
errorproneJavac("com.google.errorprone:javac:9+181-r4173-1")
```

along with dependency in step-2.
5. you can [customize/enable/disable](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-errorprone-plugin#configuration) it by tasks

```java
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.errorprone.disableWarningsInGeneratedCode = true
    options.errorprone.enabled = false // change it to true to enable
}
```

Note: As mentioned in OP comment by @jb-nizet, gralde plugin and error_prone_core has different versions and independent release cycles.

my build.gradle file

```java
buildscript {
    ext{
        errorproneVersion = '2.3.3'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "java"
    id("net.ltgt.errorprone") version "1.1.0"
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    errorprone("com.google.errorprone:error_prone_core:$errorproneVersion")
    errorproneJavac("com.google.errorprone:javac:9+181-r4173-1")
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.errorprone.disableWarningsInGeneratedCode = true
    options.errorprone.enabled = false
}
```

[Ref](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-errorprone-plugin)

[Github-error-prone](https://github.com/google/error-prone)

Comment: Hi.  A "newbie" question.  How do I see the results of error-prone?  I did a "./gradlew build" but I don't see anything extra/new in regards to error-prone.  I went to both links you shared and could not find a "see the results magic" examples.